# Can I rely on indicators like MACD if it uses my own dataset?

Tags: technical-analysis, cryptocurrency

I'm playing around with algo-trading and started collecting candle data on my own. So far I have about 3500 candles on a single cryptocurrency. While playing with MACD, I noticed that the indicators' values I get are not the same as the exchanges' and I guess it is because I don't have the full price history.
So:

1. Can I rely on these indicators that use historical data when based on the data I collected?
2. How long is long enough to be able to rely on them (if any)?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please, at least care to explain.

Comment: Why would your data be better than the exchanges? 3500 sounds like a lot but what is that resolution? If it were by the day that's like 9 years, I doubt you have that length. I can collect info every 10ms from stock markets but that doesn't necessarily make my data better or more reliable. Also momentum indicators are rarely useful for anything but day trading and even then they are iffy.

Comment: I'm just trying to implement my own strategies. I'm not sure if any exchange allows scripting or getting indicators via APIs.

Comment: But you're not implementing your own strategies, you're just using your own collected data on simple momentum indicators. There is no benefit to not using 3rd party data for this. Check IEX for a decent finance API.

Comment: No reason for downvotes here, especially with no explanation...

Answer (score 1):

Gerald Appel's MACD uses a 12 and 26 day EMA with a 9 period EMA as a signal line.  Check to see that both you and the exchange are using the same time frame (daily prices) as well as the same 12-26-9 construction.

A short period of data will differ because a simple moving average is used for the first 26 days.  With a larger amount of historical data (100 days or more), the indicator will correlate accurately with a larger database.

As for reliability, Indicators based on moving averages lag the market. MACD is one of them. Lag means in late, out late and has a higher likelihood of missing a chunk of the move as well as whipsaws in non trending markets.

If you drill down into the performance of the 12 and 26 EMAs, you'll see that after a sustained move in the underlying, if the underlying trades flat, the indicator will reverse direction and head toward zero. This is a false signal. So if the MACD is very overbought and it turns up, it may be a legitimate signal or it may be a false signal. You need a reference in the price domain to verify the signal's validity.

If the MACD turns up when above zero or down when below zero, the signal cannot be false (caused by old data being removed from the moving average calculation).  Whether it's a profitable signal depends on what happens going forward.

While there are times where MACD tests well, over the long haul it  under performs basic simple moving average crossover systems. You can look at research by Colby & Meyers or you can test this yourself.